# Proper Media Query Syntax CSS Iphone

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, media-queries, device

I was able to format a site properly for devices using an online resonsive design tester and the css declaration, for example, `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {`, but when testing the site on an actual iphone these css declarations are not being computed by the browser.

I have also tried `max-device-width` and have set the initial scale to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>.` I have also tried the previous declaration without the initial scale setting.

I also have tried: `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), screen and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {`

Also: `only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {`

None of this has worked to target the iphone yet. What am I missing to successfully target an iphone 3/4?

Comment: Try to place the media queries at the bottom of your stylesheet, i know i had the same problem before and that fix it, oddly enough. You can also test the queries with such tools as this one: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully been able to target iphone and devices using the css declaration:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px)  {
    /* put iphone css formatting here */  
}
```

for example. Thanks for the contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh... I don't trust media queries at all to do this task.

They have failed me way too many times. If you don't have any luck, go for a JS or server-side solution for detecting the device. Perhaps go for this js:

```
var pixelRat = window.devicePixelRatio;
var screenWidth = screen.width;

//iPhone Retina Display
if ( pixelRat >= 2 )
{
  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5');
  $('link[name=mainstyle').attr('href', 'css/iphoneHD.css');
}
//iPhone 3gs, 3g, Edge
else if ( pixelRat < 2 && screenWidth == 320 )
{
  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
  $('link[name=mainstyle]').attr('href', 'css/iphone.css');
}
//iPad 1 and 2
else if ( pixelRat < 2 && screenWidth == 768 )
{
  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
  $('link[name=mainstyle]').attr('href', 'css/mobile.css');
  $('link[name=loginpadstyle]').attr('href', 'css/loginpad.css');
}
//Mac OS X, Windows, Etc.
else
{
  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');
  $('link[name=mainstyle').attr('href', 'css/style.css');
}
```